# Prime divisors of $n^2-5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Q: Show that if $p$ prime divides $n^2-5$, then $p\equiv\pm1$(mod 5), with $p\neq2,5$

I have shown that the only common quadratic residues between $p$ and $5$ are $1$ and $4$. I note that $4\equiv-1$(mod 5). I'm not quite sure where to go from here, I'm quite lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $p\mid n^2-5$ implies that $n^2\equiv 5\mod{p}$, so that $5$ is a square modulo $p$. Can you finish from here? (Hint: Quadratic reciprocity.)

Comment: By quadratic reciprocity: $(\frac p5)(\frac 5p)=-1^{(\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{5-1}{2})}=(-1)^{p-1}=1$ since p is odd. Therefore, $(\frac p5)=(\frac 5p)=\pm1$. Particularly, $p\equiv\pm1$ (mod 5) - Does this sound okay?

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to say it this: given odd prime $$ q \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5 \; , \;  $$ so that Legendre symbol $$ (20| q) = (5|q) = -1.  $$

With integers $x,y.$

IF $$ x^2 - 5 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q \; , \;  $$
then both $$ x,y \equiv 0 \pmod q \; , \;  $$
so that $$ x^2 - 5 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {q^2} \; , \;  $$

Your problem says my $y=1.$ This is impossible for my prime $q$